# Identify vehicle from tail light

Tags: tail-lights, vehicle-identification

Can you tell me the make/model/year of the vehicle with this tail light?
[image]

Comment: Given the light unit doesn't appear to be actually installed in a car have you had a look for any manufacturer information/part codes on the unit itself?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The only manufacture markings are  that it is made by "Winjet" . No model or #'s. It is labelled "L", I assume for a left side mount. It is stamped in white letters 2022-06-19, which I assume is the manufacture date.

Answer (score 2):

[This tail light](https://winjetinc.com/products/tail-lights/volkswagen/golf/2006-2009/2006-2009-volkswagen-golf-led-tail-lights-chrome-red/) is for a [2006-2009 Volkswagen Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Golf_Mk5) (image source Wikipedia, public domain):

[image]

The light in your photo is indeed from the left side of the vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  I found them https://winjetinc.com/products/tail-lights/volkswagen/golf/2006-2009/2006-2009-volkswagen-golf-led-tail-lights-chrome-red/

Comment: @Harry the *answer* already found that link: if it answers you question, please upvote and **accept** it. That is how we give thanks here!